# Angular strap tooltip visible by default

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I using http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tooltips#tooltips

and i can't use Scope methods (`$show()`, `$hide()`). Help me please. How i can use this methods?

I have input in `ng-repeat`

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in data.queue" >

    <input type="text" maxlength="40"  bs-tooltip data-animation="am-flip-x" data-title="{{item.file.tooltip_title}}"> 

<div>
```

And i need to set visible tooltips if item.file.flag=== true, and then hide tooltip of beyond the 5 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get show() and hide() methods you gotta do everything on javascript side. Something like this:

**markup**

```
<div id="div1">some</div>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('someThing', ['$tooltip', '$timeout', function($tooltip, $timeout){
    return {
        link: function($scope){
            $scope.someFunction = function (item){
                $timeout(function(){
                    var target = angular.element(document.getElementById('div1'));
                    var myTooltip = $tooltip(target, { title:'tip!!', trigger:'manual', placement:'top'});
                    myTooltip.$promise.then(function() { myTooltip.show(); });

                    $timeout(function(){
                        myTooltip.$promise.then(function() { myTooltip.hide(); });
                    }, 4000);
                }, 1500);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular way of solving your problem is using, for instance, `data-bs-show="item.file.flag"`.

It will show your tooltip while `item.file.flag == true`.

The `bsShow` attribute expects a boolean value, so if you need to hide after 5 seconds, you might have another flag and set it to false after this time using `$timeout`.

It is possible to use `$show()`/`$hide()` but it's tricky and ugly so I'd avoid that if possible.